# Weblogic 12C : Guice Injector not found

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, guice, web.xml

Trying to deploy a .war file to a managed Server on Weblogic12C gives the below error:

> Caused By: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Guice Injector not found! Make sure you registered org.apache.shindig.common.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener as a listener

But, web.xml has them already(see below):

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>guice-modules</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.apache.shindig.common.PropertiesModule:
            org.apache.shindig.gadgets.DefaultGuiceModule:
            org.apache.shindig.gadgets.servlet.AuthenticationModule:
            org.apache.shindig.gadgets.oauth.OAuthModule:
            org.apache.shindig.common.cache.ehcache.EhCacheModule
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shindig.common.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Check out this link, you may be running into a CDI related issue with versions not matching correctly ? https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1433

Comment: Check this out as well, https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=559